# Consolidating duplicate code in almost identical methods

Tags: java

How could I move most of the code into one function or otherwise consolidate it? I'm not so happy with so much duplicate code. Event IntelliJ complains about it...

```
public boolean closeTrade(Trade trade) {
    for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS; i++) {
        if (closeBrokerTrade(trade)) return true; // quit loop if successfully closed

        //region sleep between checks
        if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw propagate(e);
        }
        //endregion
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean closeTrade(String ticket) {
    for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS; i++) {
        if (closeBrokerTrade(ticket)) return true; // quit loop if successfully closed

        //region sleep between checks
        if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw propagate(e);
        }
        //endregion
    }
    return false;
}

protected abstract boolean closeBrokerTrade(Trade trade);
protected abstract boolean closeBrokerTrade(String ticket);
```

Comment: I see that you could take `if(i < NUM_CHECKS - 1)` into a new method that accepts i

Comment: Post the 2 closebrokertrade() methods.

Comment: What is the relationship between a Trade and a ticket? What are the implementations of the closeBrokerTrade() methods? If they have nothing in common, you could transform the calls to `closeBrokerTrade()` into a functional interface, and use a lambda.

Comment: they are actually abstract - the `closeBrokerTrade()` methods

Comment: With 1k reputation and 4 gold badges you should know this is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you could pass the correct version of closeBrokerTrade as a lambda:

Declare the function like this:

```
public boolean closeTrade( BooleanSupplier f) {
    // ...
    if (f.getAsBoolean()) return true; // quit loop if successfully closed
    // ...
    return false;
}
```

And call it like that:

```
c.closeTrade( () -> c.closeBrokerTrade(new Trade()) );
c.closeTrade( () -> c.closeBrokerTrade("123") );
```

Comment: I've used lambdas but don't fully understand them, if I pass as a lambda does that mean that they will be evaluated within the `for loop` and not at the time of actual passing into the `closeTrade()` method?

Comment: @ycomp: I have added some code fragments to my answer. And yes, the lambdas will be evaluated in the function and not while passing them.

Comment: I'm really happy with this approach, there were other spots in the same class where it was useful. Now its really easy to read the logic in my primary method, and I just have a bunch of smaller helper methods for it to handle these loops and inputs for the loops.

Answer (score 1):

I need to see the implementation of closeBrokerTrade to be sure about the behaviour, but I would do something like this:

```
public boolean closeTrade(Trade trade) {
    String ticket = ...// generate ticket from trade in whatever way you do it, e.g. trade.getTicket() or trade.toString(), etc. etc.
    return closeTrade(ticket);
}


public boolean closeTrade(String ticket) {
    for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS*3; i++) {
        if (closeBrokerTrade(ticket)) return true; // quit loop if successfully closed

        //region sleep between checks
        if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw propagate(e);
        }
       //endregion
    }
    return false;
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong or if it is the case that you obtain the trade from the ticket.

If that's not possible, here is my suggestion:
Use generics to represent parameterized trade closing classes like this:

```
public abstract class ClosingTradeStrategy<T> {
    public boolean closeTrade(T trade) {
        for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS*3; i++) {
            if (closeBrokerTrade(trade)) return true; // quit loop if successfully closed

            //region sleep between checks
            if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) try {
                Thread.sleep(DELAY);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw propagate(e);
            }
           //endregion
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected abstract boolean closeBrokerTrade(T trade);
}
```

then you can use this to implement different trade closing strategies like this:

```
public class StringClosingTradeStrategy extends ClosingTradeStrategy<String> {
    @Override
    protected boolean closeBrokerTrade(String trade) {
        ... // implement
    }
}

public class TradeClosingTradeStrategy extends ClosingTradeStrategy<Trade> {
    @Override
    protected boolean closeBrokerTrade(Trade trade) {
        ... // implement
    }
}
```

The advantage of the second approach is that it is easily extensible to other closing strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Use interfaces, as you would if you were to use a `Comparator<T>`:

```
private static interface CloseBrokerTradeChecker <T> {
    boolean closeBrokerTrade(T t);
}

private static class CloseBrokerTradeCheckerTrade 
    implements CloseBrokerTradeChecker<Trade> {
    @Override
    boolean closeBrokerTrade(Trade trade) { ... } 
}

private static class CloseBrokerTradeCheckerTicket 
    implements CloseBrokerTradeChecker<String> {
    @Override
    boolean closeBrokerTrade(String ticket) { ... } 
}

private <T> boolean closeTrade(T t, CloseBrokerTradeChecker<T> checker) {
    for (int i=0; i< NUM_CHECKS*3; i++) {
        if (checker.closeBrokerTrade(t)) return true; // quit loop if successfully closed

        //region sleep between checks
        if (i < NUM_CHECKS -1) try {
            Thread.sleep(DELAY);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw propagate(e);
        }
        //endregion
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean closeTrade(Trade trade) {
    // TODO: extract CloseBrokerTradeCheckerTrade as a static final variable
    return closeTrade(trade, new CloseBrokerTradeCheckerTrade());
}

public boolean closeTrade(String ticket) {
    return closeTrade(ticket, new CloseBrokerTradeCheckerTicket());
}
```

Comment: you should write `checker.closeBrokerTrade(t)`. this code won't compile